# Is reusal an English word?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases, is-it-a-word

Is the word "reusal" part of the English language?

For example, given this sentence:

> ROS tries to facilitate the operation, development and code reuse of robot systems by organizing the parts of the software in independent packages.

*reuse* sounds wrong to me and I thought of *reusal* as being correct. I could only find it on some webpages, but not in an online English dictionary.

Comment: The noun form of *"reuse"* is *"reuse"* (pronounced with an /s/ rather than a /z/).

Comment: In case it's not obvious, for most useful uses of the following words, no, it is not a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[Code reuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse)" is correct. "Reusal" is not in my unabridged Webster's 3rd New International, page 1942 - reusable, reuse, reused, rev.